# Weird WCF error regarding update to serializable class

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Here's the setup, I had a collection class in `MyAssembly` that looked like so:

```
[Serializable()]
public class MyCollection : List<MyItem> //MyItem is also serializable
{
    public string MyProperty{ get; set; }

    //some methods for use by the current assembly
}
```

And I had an application that made a reference to a wcf service, which in turn had a reference to this `MyAssembly`.

**The problem:** In the past we've made many changes to the classes without any issues, however I recently added a couple of new methods(no new properties) to `MyCollection` and after recompiling and redeploying the wcf service, the app consuming the service would all of a suddent return a null `MyCollection` when being called.

**The solution and question:** Updating the service reference in the app brought everything back to normal, but my question is why? I was under the understanding that new items could be added to your classes without having to update the reference unless something was changed or deleted. Can someone explain this or refer me somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

When you add reference to wcf service a copy (not actual real copy, more like a proxy objects) of service objects are placed on client side. So when you update wcf service objects client is still left only with old (invalid) copy. 
You should always update reference on client side when changes are made on wcf server ServiceContract or DataContract.

Comment: Right, I understand that's the case if you "update" or "delete" members of a class, but not if you "add" members. We've added members to our classes many times and haven't come across this problem before.

Comment: Were you using shared library for passing DataContract entites?

Comment: Even if you add story is the same. New member is just not serialized back to object properly if its not declared inside DataContract

Comment: Yes, I was using a shared library.

Comment: In this case its possible you were experiencing this. I had similar case. You can remove shared library from cilent and use just proxy objects generated by vs.